# Display dynamic integer or double

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a school project and I must "measure" the sound, like decibel. I have search online for tutorials etc. and found some great scripts. I can visually see that my mobile device detects a sound, but I want to see a number too, how loud the sounds are.

I can display a `double` or `int`in a `textview`, but this number doesn't change in the `textview` wile the `integer` or `double` itselfs should and does change, but I can't see this. Maybe it doesn't update?

this is the most important code in my main activity.

```
private TextView tv;
double amp = 0.0;

public void run() {
    double amp = mSensor.getAmplitudeEMA();
    if (mTestMode) updateDisplay(amp);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mSensor = new SoundMeter();
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amplitude);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(amp)); 
    mTestMode = true;
    start();
}
```

So when I run this code, I see 0.0 on my screen, but when I talk, the `double amp`should change, but I still see 0.0.

And no, the script to detect sound works, I know that becouse you can see it visualy, with an animation that you speek, 3 bars when the sound is low, and more bars when the soud gets louder.

But my question is, why doesn't the `double amp` update itselfs? Why doesn't the 0.0 change?

Comment: every time the value changed you have to call tv.setText

Comment: yes, call tv.setText()

Comment: @bvane Isn't it an easy way?

Comment: Yes, wasn't thinking straight, it is! Thanx for the tip blackbelt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void run() {
    if (mTestMode) {
        double amp = mSensor.getAmplitudeEMA();
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(amp));
    }
}
```